# Changing a structs string

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, lex, c-strings

I'm using lex to implement a scanner. I want to build a symbol table while parsing. I have two structs, SymbolEntry and SymbolTable (below). Most of the time, when I call my function for inserting a symbol (registerID, also below) I have all the information for the entry. However, when I have a constant I also want to get it's value, but that is not immediately available when I first create the entry. When I try to change the entries value later in the code, I'm invalidating the whole memory block used by that entry and the name and value are printing garbage.

Here are the two structs:

```
typedef struct{
    char* type;
    char* name;
    char* value;
} SymbolEntry;
typedef struct{
    SymbolEntry *entries;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
} SymbolTable;
```

This is the registerID function, called when an `{id}` is matched. `yytext` contains the ID.

```
int registerID(char* type){
    //create a new symbol entry with the specified type and name and a default value
    SymbolEntry e;
    e.type = type;
    e.name = (char *)calloc(yyleng+1, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(e.name, yytext);
    e.value = "";
    prevSym = insertSymbol(&table, e);
    return prevSym;
}
```

This is the relevant code for `insertSymbol(SymbolTable* st, SymbolEntry entry)`. `pos` is always the last element in the array when inserting (otherwise the entry isn't unique and `pos` is just returned).

```
st->entries[pos].name = (char *)calloc(strlen(entry.name)+1, sizeof(char));
st->entries[pos].type = (char *)calloc(strlen(entry.type)+1, sizeof(char));
st->entries[pos].value = (char *)calloc(strlen(entry.value)+1, sizeof(char));
strcpy(st->entries[pos].name, entry.name);
strcpy(st->entries[pos].type, entry.type);
strcpy(st->entries[pos].value, entry.value);
```

Later, after the lex framework has matched the value immediately following a CONSTANTs name, this code is performed (directly in the rule for `<CONSTANT_VAL>{number}`)

```
table.entries[prevSym].value = (char *)calloc(yyleng+1, sizeof(char));
strcpy(table.entries[prevSym].value, yytext);
```

Why does this invalidate the the SymbolEntry at this position in the array, and how can I safely change the contents of `value`?

**EDIT:**
  It doesn't only happen with constants. The first two `SymbolEntry`s are always garbage. I'm assuming that probably means they ALL are, but the others just haven't been overwritten.

Also, it seems like subsequent calls to `registerID` is causing the data to get corrupted. With just 9 symbols, only the first two are garbage, with 34, it's the first 7. Adding more text to parse without variables did not cause any issues.

**SOLVED**
Well it turns out that I just accidentally deleted a line somewhere along the way and that's what introduced the bug. I accidentally erased my call to `initSymbolTable`. Thanks to chux for asking me how I initialized the table. Sorry about that.

Comment: How are you allocating st->entries[pos] ?  One possibility is you're writing past your allocated memory.

Comment: I start it sized for 16, but if ever `size == capacity` then I reallocate double the size. This check is done after every insert operation.

Comment: Also, I've tried allocating the SymbolEntry array to 1024 and still it's invalid.

Comment: I assume this is just a typo, but just in case: you call insertSymbol() in your code but reference insertSymbolTable() later.

Comment: Ah yes, that is a typo. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

2 potential problems.

1 - Compare

```
// Fields set with non-malloc'ed memory
e.type = type;
e.value = "";
// Fields set with malloc'ed memory
st->entries[pos].type = (char *)calloc(strlen(entry.type)+1, sizeof(char));
st->entries[pos].value = (char *)calloc(strlen(entry.value)+1, sizeof(char));
strcpy(st->entries[pos].type, entry.type);
strcpy(st->entries[pos].value, entry.value);
```

Both of these set the fields to valid memory and in the second case, dynamically fill the memory.  The concern is subsequent use.  How does OP know to `free()` or `realloc()` the second kind and not the first.  Further concern: With `registerID(char* type)`, how do we know the value passed to `type` is still valid way later when that pointer is used via field `type`.  Suggest:

```
e.type = strdup(type); // or the usual strlen()+1, malloc() and copy
e.value = strdup("");
```

2 - The type and setting of `yyleng` are not shown.  Maybe it is not big enough as compared to `strlen(e.name)`, etc.?

[Edit] after review, I real think `e.type = type;` is the problem.  `e.type` needs its own copy of `type`.

Minor: Consider

```
// st->entries[pos].type = (char *)calloc(strlen(entry.type)+1, sizeof(char));
// strcpy(st->entries[pos].type, entry.type);
size_t Length = strlen(entry.type) + 1;
st->entries[pos].type = malloc(Length);
memcpy(st->entries[pos].type, entry.type, Length);
```

Comment: I changed all the assignments to `strdup()` calls. `yyleng` is defined by lex and is the length of `yytext`. Each field in each record is ONLY created once, with the exception of `value` for `type == CONSTANT`. Then it changes in only one of two specific places. At this point (even without constants in the input file) the top 3/32 SymbolEntries are corrupted. I don't see how this can be if at every step `strdup()` is used. Worst-case, I should be dealing with a memory overflow instead.

Comment: Hmmm.  For debug purposes, consider `e.name = strdup(yytext)` and `table.entries[prevSym].value = strdup(yytext)` - maybe you've done that all ready.  If this does not fix things, the issue must be in un-posted code.

Comment: @Jaws212 How is memory for `st`  allocated?

Comment: There's a global variable `SymbolTable table`. Its reference is passed in `inputSymbol(&table, e)` in registerID. I'm not sure what you're asking me to do with the `strdup(yytext)` statements, but I've changed all of the `st->entries[pos].*** = strdup(***)` to use literal strings and still the issue is there.

Comment: What value do you put in `table.entries` or `st->entries`?  (Note: not what value do you put in `st->entries[pos]...`)

Comment: The issue was resolved. It turns out I was just an idiot. I've updated the post accordingly.

Comment: @Jaws212 Bug gone!  "And another one gone, and another one gone, Another one bites the dust."